# Are sexual/romantic characteristics correllated with blood type?

Tags: sexuality, physiology

I saw this assertion on many sources, here's one:

http://www.japanzine.jp/article/jz/521/love-sex-blood-types

> Many Japanese people believe that just as different blood types are incompatible, so are people of different blood types. Below is a list of different blood types, and the sexual or romantic characteristics associated with them. *(long list follows)*

Answer (score 1):

Much like the Zodiac, this seems to be "for entertainment purposes only" at best, and a self-fulfilling prophecy at worst. Or vice versa, depending on your appreciation of pseudoscience. According to this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_type_personality_theory) on the subject with over 40 references, the link between blood types and personality have been researched frequently, but altogether inconclusively. So for now, science says...Nope.